# Is the term "Quantum GIS" trademarked?

Tags: qgis, license

We need to link to Quantum GIS on a major official website. My legal department asks me if "Quantum GIS" is trademarked. Is it?

Comment: Check out the website under about.

Comment: @lewis why not answering the question if you know it?

Comment: Thanks Lewis, while the about page does mention the origin of the name, it currently says nothing about whether it is trademarked or not. Right?

Comment: I reply below Satri

Comment: More open source projects are registering their names to protect them, see the example of issues surrounding Firefox: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Firefox#Naming

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, QGIS is now trademarked, see https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/governance/trademark/index.html for more details.

---

*Previous answer:* No it is not yet trademarked.

Comment: Tim, you say "not yet", does that mean you (plural) intend to undertake that at some point?

Comment: @mattwilkie We are planning to get at least an EU trademark on the name QGIS (Quantum GIS now no longer being the official name of the project). Unfortunately we do not have the financial power to obtain a world-wide trademark.

Comment: now is a Trademark: https://oami.europa.eu/eSearch/#details/trademarks/012702643

Comment: beloging to QGIS community: http://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/governance/trademark/index.html

Answer (score 18):

- The phrase, "Quantum GIS", is not found in the [US Trademark
  electronic search](http://tess2.uspto.gov/bin/gate.exe?f=searchss&state=4006%3alu4imy.1.1).
- Trademark status is not mentioned on the [Quantum GIS website](http://www.qgis.org/),
  nor is,
- a trademark symbol nor statement used in the documentation.
- The [OSGeo website](http://www.osgeo.org/content/foundation/legal/trademark_faq.html) does have two trademark-related pages, but
  they only mention various OSGeo and FOSS trademarks.

You might check the archives of the [mailing lists](http://www.qgis.org/en/community/mailing-lists.html), particularly the project steering committee.

Comment: This is a bit dated QGIS is now trademarked in the EU. http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/116719/6052

Answer (score 10):

Their wiki discusses how to [cite the software](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Citation_Repository)

Cite the QGIS project in general

`Quantum GIS Development Team, <YEAR>. Quantum GIS Geographic Information System. Open Source Geospatial Foundation Project. http://qgis.osgeo.org`

Answer (score 7):

Please note: QGIS name and logo are now under trademark http://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/governance/trademark/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Because I like to encourage research, 
however, I take your point.
My research indicates that the answer can be gleaned from the documentation.

"This document is the original user guide of the described software Quantum GIS. The software and hardware
described in this document are in most cases registered trademarks and are therefore subject to the legal
requirements. Quantum GIS is subject to the GNU General Public License. Find more information on the
Quantum GIS Homepage"

http://www.qgis.org.